# How to host PHP scripts on iOS without Jailbreaking?

Tags: php, iphone, webserver

I am writing an internal app for my company,

It's a developer tool, which runs on a Website hosted in-device. ( I'm not planning to sell this App through the App Store, I know that downloaded code can't be executed in-device )

I was wondering if there's a way to run a PHP enabled web server from iOS without Jailbreaking, I'm aware of an nginx build that supports PHP for jailbroken iOS devices and I also know there's no problem in running an embedded web server like [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) on iOS.

Any insights/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a weird app design

Comment: Not really if you are aiming cross-platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though neither of these works with PHP as they are now, they're both pretty solid http servers that will work fine on iOS and so will take you at least part of the way:

**[CocoaHTTPServer](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/)**: A much-improved version of Apple's simpler cocoahttpserver example.

**[SimpleHTTPServer](http://culturedcode.com/cocoa/)**: Cultured Code's basic Cocoa web server.

I don't believe there's anything on the market currently that will interpret PHP under iOS. However, since Apache and PHP both run fine on OS X and iOS is effectively an extension/modification of OS X, it's likely not mindblowingly difficult to port them over.

It will surely require accessing a number of private APIs, but as you say, you've not trying to sell it in the App Store, so it's at least within the realm of possibility.